# C++ how do I store different shape with different coordinate into a vector

Tags: c++

I'm using inheritance to calculate the area of 3 shapes: a square, rect and cross

so since square and rect all has 4 set of coord x,y while cross has 12 set of x,y..

my shape consist of 
-Shape Name
- area
- all coordinates

I have a total of 4 classes
1) shape2d
2) square
3) rect
4) cross

so is there actually a way to store it in a vector?

Comment: are you sure you want square and rect to be in 2 different classes?

Comment: To utilize polymorphism, you need to store pointers or references to to the objects. Store `std::shared_ptr<shape2d>` in the vector.

Comment: You store a pointer (either raw `shape2d*` or, preferably, some kind of smart pointer such as `shared_ptr<shape2d>`). You also put all your type-specific calculations to virtual functions, and do not use casts.

Comment: I didn't want to but it's part of a requirement..

Comment: A better design would still make `square` a subclass of `rect`, IMHO.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's not as trivial as it might seem: [Circle-ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)

Answer (score 5):

Since vector stores real copies of objects you will need to build a vector to pointers of type Shape. 
This way the vector stores a copy of the pointer which is no problem at all.

However it means you will have to manage the memory of these shapes (when to delete the pointers).

You can do this by making sure that the "owner" of the pointer deletes them when he removes them from the vector.
Or by using unique_ptr or shared_ptr to manage the memory for you.